# How can I make the output of this form input an array?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a form in which users can select multiple options from a drop down menu. This form looks something like the following:

```
<html>

<form method='post'>
<select name='tag' multiple>
<option value='opt1'>Option 1</option>
<option value='opt2'>Option 2</option>
<option value='opt3'>Option 3</option>
<option value='opt4'>Option 4</option>
<option value='opt5'>Option 5</option>
</select>
<input type='submit' Value='Submit'>
</form>

<? include('select.php'); ?>

</html>
```

Where the php file contains the following simple code:

```
<?php

if($_POST){

$tag = $_POST['tag'];
echo $tag;

}

?>
```

The end result of this code is a drop down menu from which you may select multiple options. However, when you click submit, it only echos one of the options that the user selected.

How can I make an array of all of the options selected by the user?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try Changes the to `<select name='tag' multiple>` to

```
<select name='tag[]' multiple>
```

For PHP side :

```
foreach ($_POST['tag'] as $selectedOption){
    echo $selectedOption."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name='tag[]' multiple>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your select tag from this   to
this:

```
<select name='tag[]' multiple>
```

In PHP:

```
foreach ($_POST['tag'] as $option_selected){
    echo $option_selected;
}
```